Wiring Leviton Combo 3 way switch (Part number 5645–W) on a 3 way lighting circuit
I just bought a Leviton Combo 3 way switch to replace an other three way switch because a need an outlet.
In the outlet there are 2 cables, one black and white and ground wire an a second with white,red,black and ground.Withe wire are connected together but not to the outlet.
Before I install  the new 3 way it I  took picture of the previous wiring. (See pictures). I identify the black wire connected to the common with tape.
I use a voltmeter to find if there were other common wire. I found the black wire, identified as such on the previous switch only read 6 volt. The second black wire read 47 volts and the red one 120 volts.
I tried to connect the wire on the new three way as they were in the previous one but only the light switch works.
Can someone help me to figure out how to complete the setup?


If you used a combo switch/ outlet, https://www.amazon.com/Leviton-5645-W-Combination-Commercial-Grounding/dp/B000U3BULU/ref=asc_df_B000U3BULU/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=693689914505&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1568957581293829887&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9012306&hvtargid=pla-349886108094&psc=1&mcid=602e69dd480d3f2cb8e62cd1ebf4555a   you need a neutral on the silver screw of the combo, otherwise the outlet will not work.

You state that there are two cables, each with a white wire. When I squint at the photograph I think there are three white wires in the yellow wire nut. Which is correct?

I don't think this is going to work, at least not easily.
The way 3-way switches work is that one switch has common (hot) + two travelers (alternating switched hot). The other switch has two travelers (alternating switched hot) and common (switched hot). In addition, there is a third wire that, in your setup, is neutral. There are other configurations, but I am pretty sure that is what you have.
The problem is that to power a receptacle you need hot + neutral. You have neutral - that's the whites connected together - just add another white wire to that group and connect it to the receptacle ("N" in the Leviton instructions). The black and red wires that are together (same cable, same color screws on the old switch) go to the traveler connections on the new switch ("A1" and "A2" in the Leviton instructions).
But the receptacle needs always hot, not switched hot. Based on measuring 120V to ground on the red wire, I suspect your other switch has hot as common and this switch has switched hot as common. The way to verify is to (carefully!) flip the other switch and see if now black is 120V and red is 0V (or some low phantom voltage). Assuming that's the case, this setup won't work here because you won't have an always hot wire to power the receptacle.

There is another solution, but it gets a little more involved:

Replace the other 3-way switch with a smart switch of some sort that can use "remote" switches and which does not require both travelers to communicate with a remote switch - i.e., the remote is wireless or can work with just one of the travelers.
Replace this single gang box with a double-gang box
Replace this switch with a "remote"
Reuse one of the travelers as always hot (preferably black, though technically it doesn't matter - black or red is OK)
Install an ordinary receptacle next to the "remote"

